# Helper class is not returning image name which is stored in SQLite databse

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to retrieve image paths from SQLite database and display corresponding images on the ImageView. The problem is, helper class is not returning the image name, so that, I am unable to display the image in the ImageView. Please see the following code for helper.class

```
public static final String GETSD = "select DISTINCT FileName from Photos where 
 last_disp_TimeStamp in (select MIN(last_disp_TimeStamp) from Photos where 
 DisplayCount in (select MIN(DisplayCount) from Photos));";

public static final String UPDATE_DISP = "update Photos set DisplayCount = 
 Displaycount+1 where last_disp_TimeStamp in (select MIN(last_disp_TimeStamp) 
 from Photos where DisplayCount in (select MIN(DisplayCount) from Photos));";

public static final String UPDATE_TIMESTAMP = "update Photos set 
 last_disp_TimeStamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where FileName in (select FileName from
 Photos where last_disp_TimeStamp in (select MIN(last_disp_TimeStamp) from Photos 
 where DisplayCount in (select MIN(DisplayCount) from Photos)));";

    public String getSDPath() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor c;
        SQLiteDatabase myDB ;
        String commonpath = "/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/";

        String result="";
        String h = "";
         try {

              myDB=this.openDataBase();                   

                  c=myDB.rawQuery(GETSD,null);
                  myDB.execSQL(UPDATE_DISP);

                  myDB.execSQL(UPDATE_TIMESTAMP);


                 if (c != null ) {
                     if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                     do {

                         // put your code to get data from cursor                      
                         int img = c.getColumnIndex("FileName");
                         result = c.getString(img);
                         h=commonpath+result;
                             final String imageFilePath = c.getString(img);
                         Log.v("IMAGE PATH====>>>> ", imageFilePath);


                  }while (c.moveToNext());
                     }

                  }



                  if(c != null)
                 {
                     myDB.close();
                     c.close();
                  }                    
                  }catch(SQLException sqle){

                  throw sqle;

                  }

        return h;
    }
```

The queries are working fine, when I test them on SQLite browser I don't have any problem with queries. I have checked the database file in `/data/data/com.example.myappname/databases/` folder. I have the required photos in `/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/`.

The path this function is returning is, /storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/. But the expected string from this function is, something like /storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/xxx.png

The string "xxx.png" is stored in database and with the query GET_SD, I am retrieving the name of the image.

Comment: Put an `android.util.Log` statement in your `cursor` loop to confirm that the database is returning the image name(s). Also it's probably a good idea to run your update statements after you've processed your `cursor`.

Comment: Thank you @StevenWolfe, for your reply. Am sorry for the late response, please see the updated code, I have added Log as per your suggestion. But also there's no change. I did not get any Log statement in LOGCAT.

Comment: No worries. Comment out your `myDB.execSQL(UPDATE_DISP);` and `myDB.execSQL(UPDATE_TIMESTAMP);` statements in your code and run it again. Any change?

Comment: If I comment them, how can I retrieve the image names?

Comment: Something is causing your `GETSD` query to return zero results. I'm just wondering whether the updates are causing the problem.

Comment: no @StevenWolfe, I have tested the same statements in SQLite Browser just now, they are working fine.

Comment: Now, I am getting the image name in Log meaasge, but I could not return the same.